# OpenCV errors and warnings with visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, opencv3.0, imread

I am getting starting with openCV but I am having trouble running a simple program involving imshow with an image. Have a feeling it something I have configured wrong. First of all,  I am getting an "Exeption Unhandled" error, details: 
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFEB0B3A839 in opencv_test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000F1BE36F268.

Running Visual Studio Pro 2019 also tried Visual Studio Community 2019
Running opencv 4.1.2 also tried 3.4.8  and tried configuring it with both vc15 and vc14

I have followed both of these tutorial exactly as far as I know but problem still exists.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_4fNNyk1aw&list=WL&index=18&t=603s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oi3HaBH8RC4

Something interesting about this is that I am getting something around 150 warnings(listed below) when I run the program with just the one exception.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    Mat test = imread("C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/opencv_test/me.jpg");
    namedWindow("myWin");
    imshow("myWin", test);

}
```

I have also tried running it by declaring test a number of ways:

```
Mat test = imread("C:\\Users\\\Austin\Desktop\\\opencv_test\\me.jpg", 1);
Mat test = imread("C:\\Users\\\Austin\Desktop\\\opencv_test\\me.jpg");
Mat test = imread("C:Users\Austin\Desktop\opencv_test\me.jpg");
Mat test = imread("me.jpg", 1);
Mat test = imread("me.jpg");
Mat test = imread("me.jpg", CV_IMAGE_LOAD_UNCHANGED);


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\async.hpp  73  
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   301 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   301 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   301 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::cuda::HostMem::AllocType' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   385 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   482 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   482 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   482 
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::cuda::FeatureSet' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cuda.inl.hpp   605 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::float16_t::w' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\cvdef.h    731 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray::flags' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    116 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray::obj' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    116 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    581 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    581 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    581 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    610 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    610 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    610 
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'data+step.p[0]*i0'.     opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1181    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1419    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1444    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::MatStep::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1554    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::MatStep::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1560    
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'this->data+this->step.p[0]*i0'.     opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    1943    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2245    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2245    
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2245    
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm'. See line 2686 for an earlier location where this can occur  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2689    
Warning C6011   Dereferencing NULL pointer 'm'. See line 2700 for an earlier location where this can occur  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    2703    
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cv::UMatUsageFlags' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    3648    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    3937    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp    3961    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   542 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,4,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   542 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<float,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   542 
Warning C6294   Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   559 
Warning C6201   Index '2' is out of valid index range '0' to '1' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'this->val'.   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   559 
Warning C6294   Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   567 
Warning C6201   Index '3' is out of valid index range '0' to '2' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'this->val'.   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   567 
Warning C6294   Ill-defined for-loop:  initial condition does not satisfy test.  Loop body not executed.    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   575 
Warning C6201   Index '4' is out of valid index range '0' to '3' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'this->val'.   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   575 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   668 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,4,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   668 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<float,3,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   668 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::Matx<double,4,1>::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   858 
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '12' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '16' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '24' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '32' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read. opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C6385   Reading invalid data from 'this->val':  the readable size is '8' bytes, but 'i' bytes may be read.  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\matx.hpp   1124    
Warning C26439  This kind of function may not throw. Declare it 'noexcept' (f.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\ptr.inl.hpp    258 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::BorderConst' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::BorderMode' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::ID' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::align' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::alphaChannel' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::channelSeq' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::colorModel' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::dataOrder' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::depth' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::height' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::imageData' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::imageDataOrigin' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::imageId' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::imageSize' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::maskROI' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::nChannels' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::nSize' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::origin' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::roi' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::tileInfo' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::width' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable '_IplImage::widthStep' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  359 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::<unnamed-tag>::cols' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::<unnamed-tag>::height' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::<unnamed-tag>::rows' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::<unnamed-tag>::width' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::data' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::hdr_refcount' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::refcount' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::step' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMat::type' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  498 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMatND::data' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  708 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMatND::dim' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  708 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMatND::dims' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  708 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMatND::hdr_refcount' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  708 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMatND::refcount' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  708 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvMatND::type' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  708 
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvScalar::val' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\types_c.h  1392    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    562 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '<<' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '<<' to avoid overflow (io.2).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    562 
Warning C6297   Arithmetic overflow:  32-bit value is shifted, then cast to 64-bit value.  Results might not be an expected value.  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    562 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<__int64,1>::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    1016    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<__int64,1>::ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    1016    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<double,1>::buf' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    1016    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::AutoBuffer<double,1>::ptr' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\utility.hpp    1016    
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v14::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::pd' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v14::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::pi' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v14::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::ps' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v14::DictValue::<unnamed-tag>::pv' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\dnn\dnn.inl.hpp 239 
Warning C6269   Possibly incorrect order of operations:  dereference ignored.   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\any.h 97  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::flann_algorithm_t' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\kdtree_index.h    59  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::flann_centers_init_t' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\kmeans_index.h    59  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_max_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_mean_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_median_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_min_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::bucket_size_std_dev' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::lsh::LshStats::n_buckets_' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   96  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::lsh::LshTable<unsigned char>::SpeedLevel' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   279 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   359 
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\lsh_table.h   360 
Warning C26495  Variable 'cvflann::UntypedMatrix::type' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\matrix.h  97  
Warning C26812  The enum type 'cvflann::flann_datatype_t' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\flann\saving.h  51  
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc.hpp 4890    
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc.hpp 4907    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::ascii' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::cyrillic' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::dx' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::font_face' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::greek' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::hscale' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::line_type' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::nameFont' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6). opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131    
Warning C26495  Variable 'CvFont::shear' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    opencv_test C:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\imgproc\imgproc_c.h 1131
```

And more

Comment: 3 \ in a row is wrong. It should be 2. You could avoid this by just using / instead  of \\

Comment: do you changing 
Mat test = imread("C:\\Users\\\Austin\Desktop\\\opencv_test\\me.jpg", 1);  
to   
Mat test = imread("C:/Users/Austin/Desktop/opencv_test/me.jpg");
still running into same issue

Comment: Upodate: new expeption:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE29935F2D (opencv_world348d.dll) in opencv_test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000024. occurred

Seems like it has something to do with opencv_world348.dll file. I originally had copied that file to the working directory.